# Maximize absolute difference

Tags: arrays, algorithm, maximize

Given an array of coins each having some value.Array size is N. You can change the value of any any coin except the first and last coin. You can change the value of ith coin to half of sum
of value of (i-1)th and (i+1)th coin but for doing so, two condition needs to be satisfied.

(1) value of both (i-1)th and (i+1)th coin should be even and

(2) if jth coin's value is changed after ith coin's value then j should be greater than i

Now your task is to maximize the absolute difference between the sum of values of 1st half of  coins of array and values of 2nd half of the coins of array. If array size is odd ignore middle element.

Can anyone suggest me the algo to find the answer.

The task is to find the maximum absolute diffeerence.

My algo:
1. find sums of left half and right half
2. if left half> right half maximize left half by making operations given and minize left half but i am not geting correct answer.

PS: I attended one interview one week before. It was asked there I could not figure out the approach.

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a homework service. How many times does this have to be said each day? :(

Comment: This seems to be hard problem. Could you provide the source of the problem.

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you accept one or leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a more sophisticated algorithm than brute force. You simply should try all the possible things and return the best result. I recommend a recursive approach. Write a recursive function that takes the input list and an index as its parameters. The function tries to change the number residing on that index and will return the best outcome. In the end you should print the best outcome. It sounds complicated but in action it is fairly easy. Take a look at this code:

```
def func(input_list, index):
    # if we have reached the end of the list
    # we compute the result and return it
    L = input_list[:]
    if index == len(L): 
    # return absolute difference of the two halves
        return abs ( sum(L[:len(L)/2]) - sum(L[int(len(L)/2.0 + 1):]) )

    #result of not changing this item
    no_change = func(L, index+1)

    #check if it is possible to change this item
    change = 0
    if index-1 >= 0 and index+1 < len(L) and L[index-1]%2==0 and L[index+1]%2==0:
        #result of changing this item if possible
        L[index] = (L[index-1] + L[index+1])/2
        change = func(L, index+1)

    #return the maximum result of changing and not changing
    best = max(no_change, change)
    return best


L = [10, 4, 22, 8, 64]
print func(L, 0)
```

which prints

```
93
```

For the final list of `[10, 4, 22, 43, 64]`

But keep in mind that this method is inefficient and won't work for large inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some optimisations possible on the brute force algorithm.

We could make the algorithm to store at each index the possible sums calculated from all data that follows to the right. That information would be filled in during the backtracking out of recursion.

Example: to simplify I will only consider maximising the first half sum, and minimising the second half sum.

```
[4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 1, 4]
```

The algorithm would go depth-first towards the last element of the array, and then store the best sum there, only considering what follows at the right. Since there is nothing at the right the sum is 4. But as we want to minimise, we switch the sign. So we store something like this:

```
[4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 1,  4]
                   -4
```

Then we backtrack. There we have currently two possibilities: we leave the 1 as-is, or we use the average of the surrounding values (i.e. 4):

```
[4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 1,  4]
                   -4 
               -5
[4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 4,  4]
                   -4
               -8
```

Both the values -5 and -8 will be stored in a hash, so that for value 1 we can find -5, and for value 4 we can find -8.

At a certain point in the algorithm we will try with the value 6 at the second array element (instead of the 1) and then recurse again. When we arrive at the one-but-last element, we find that the possible values are again 1 or 4 (if nothing else was altered at the left side), and so we don't have to recurse deeper: we can read the sums from the hash we maintain at that index.

This system can bring a lot of savings in larger arrays, making sure the algorithm only goes deeper into recursion when really necessary. Obviously it comes at a cost in terms of space.

Then the whole algorithm can be executed a second time, but then swapping the sign. Of those two outcomes the best solution is taken, maximising the absolute value.

By passing the possibly altered element value as a function argument, we can avoid creating multiple arrays, and just work with the input array. On the other hand, the hash -- created at each index -- takes some space.

Here is the algorithm in JavaScript, in which I did not use any fancy features, so it should be easy to follow:

```js
function getMaxSum(a) {
    // Index of the element in the middle. If integer,
    // the element at this index will not play a role in any sum:
    var mid = (a.length-1)/2;
    // Two results, one that maximises the left sum and minimises the right sum
    // The other minimises the left and maximises the right:
    var result, result2, b;

    function recurse(prevVal, index, sign, hash = []) {
        var val, nextVal, sum, result, avg;
        
        val = a[index];
        if (index >= a.length-1) {
            // At the last element there are no choices left:
            return { sum: -sign*(prevVal+val), nextVal: val, hash: [] };
        }
        if (!hash[index]) hash[index] = [];
        nextVal = a[index+1];
        result = { sum: -Infinity, nextVal: 0, hash: hash[index] };
        // Loop through the 2 possibilities (in general): take value as is, or 
        // take the average of previous and next value:
        while (true) {
            // If the result from this position onward is not know, calculate
            // it via a recursive call:
            if (!hash[index][val]) hash[index][val] = recurse(val, index+1, sign, hash);
            // Add the previous value to the best sum at this point, using the appropriate sign,
            // and store the result in a hash table, for future reference:
            sum = hash[index][val].sum + (index-1 > mid ? -1 : index-1 < mid ? 1 : 0) * sign * prevVal;
            if (sum > result.sum) {
                result.sum = sum;
                result.nextVal = val;
            }
            if (prevVal % 2 || nextVal % 2 || (avg = (prevVal + nextVal)/2) === val) break;
            val = avg;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Calculate both results
    result = recurse(a[0], 1, 1, []);
    result2 = recurse(a[0], 1, -1, []);
    // Pick the best one.
    if (Math.abs(result2.sum) > Math.abs(result.sum)) result = result2;

    // Rebuild the array corresponding to the best result:
    b = [a[0]];
    while (result) {
        b.push(result.nextVal);
        result = result.hash[result.nextVal];
    }
    return b;
}

// Sample data
var a = [4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 1, 4];
console.log(' input: ' + a);
// Apply algorithm
var b = getMaxSum(a, 1);
// Print result
console.log('result: ' + b);
```